# Connection Time Out Using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, database, apache, pdo

I have a quick question on utilizing a database from a remote server from my website.
My problem is that I have no problem connecting to the database using the password, database, username and host within HieidiSQL to connect, but when I use PDO it throws an error, so I can connect remotely, but I'm stumped at this point.
Error Thrown (Cleaned up for easier reading):

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection timed out' in /customers/0/1/9/doxramosgaming.org/httpd.www/functions.d/db/db.class.php:36
Stack trace:
#0 /customers/0/1/9/doxramosgaming.org/httpd.www/functions.d/db/db.class.php(36): PDO->__construct('mysql:host=104....', user', 'mypassword')
#1 /customers/0/1/9/doxramosgaming.org/httpd.www/functions.d/db/db.class.php(47): db->__construct()
#2 /customers/0/1/9/doxramosgaming.org/httpd.www/config.php(20): require_once('/customers/0/1/...')
#3 /customers/0/1/9/doxramosgaming.org/httpd.www/index.php(2): require_once('/customers/0/1/...')
#4 {main}
  thrown in /customers/0/1/9/doxramosgaming.org/httpd.www/functions.d/db/db.class.php on line 36
```

Attempted Resolves:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO myuser@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'mypassword';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
sudo service mysql restart
```

my.cnf

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Please notice that's it's not set to 127.0.0.1 and not commented, so please don't tell me to comment out the bind address. I can connect through HeidiSQL on my PC which tells me remote connections are allowed already.

connection File:

```
class db extends pdo{
//Website Variables

public $sitedb = '';
public $siteconfig;
public $sitesettings = array(
    'host'      => _SITEHOST,
    'database'  => _SITEDB,
    'username'  => _SITEUSER,
    'password'  => _SITEPASS,
);
public $realmdb = '';
public $realmconfig;
public $realmsettings = array(
    'host'      => _REALMHOST,
    'database'  => _REALMDB,
    'username'  => _REALMUSER,
    'password'  => _REALMPASS,
);
public function __construct(){

    $this->sitedb = new PDO(
        "mysql:host={$this->sitesettings['host']};" .
        "dbname={$this->sitesettings['database']};" .
        "charset=utf8",
        "{$this->sitesettings['username']}",
        "{$this->sitesettings['password']}"
    );
     $this->realmdb = new PDO(
        "mysql:host={$this->realmsettings['host']};" .
        "dbname={$this->realmsettings['database']};" .
        "charset=utf8",
        "{$this->realmsettings['username']}",
        "{$this->realmsettings['password']}"
    );


    $this->sitedb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $this->realmdb->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE, PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

}


}

$db = new db();
```

The passwords and everything is all set within my config file that loads the db.connection file. It works on my local server, just not when I upload it to my webserver.
All Database names, passwords, etc are correct, so it's not an issue there.

### Just as another test I ran mysql from my home computer to the server and it connected no problem in a split second. I don't understand what the issue is here.

I modified my connection setting to see if I could find out what was going on at all to

```
try {
         $this->realmdb = new PDO(
            "mysql:host={$this->realmsettings['host']};" .
            "dbname={$this->realmsettings['database']};" .
            "charset=utf8",
            "{$this->realmsettings['username']}",
            "{$this->realmsettings['password']}"
        );
        }
        catch(PDOException $e) {
            echo "PDO Realm Failure:";
        }
```

After the edit I'm given:

> PDO Realm Failure: Fatal error: Call to a member function
>   setAttribute() on string in
>   /customers/0/1/9/doxramosgaming.org/httpd.www/functions.d/db/db.class.php
>   on line 49

Could it not be constructing the database connection that way for some reason live even though it worked on my local server?

Just found some relevant information. When I connect to the realm server and run locally it all works, so it has to be in my web host, but I'm not sure where to even look.

Comment: You should not post your root with password and the domain in the future. If I were you I d Change it first thing

Comment: Thanks for the catch. Changed